# Error while calling function in a module in nodejs

Tags: node.js

This is the file users.js

```
exports.password_encryptor = function password_encryptor() {
    return "blablablablablameumeu";
}
```

And here is the other file accounts.js

```
var users = require("./users");
console.log("password encrypted is " + users.password_encryptor());
```

I have an error stating:

> password_encryptor is undefined.

I have already tried to debug this for 2 hours but without success

Comment: Is that the complete users.js file ? No import in that file ?

Comment: my users.js file is very long , but there is at the bottom of the file an other line "module.exports = aJsonData;

Comment: It is difficult to know exactly this way, could you try with module.exports.password_encryptor = ... Take care of the module work in front of exports. Let us know if this fix your problem.

Comment: Of course `module.exports = aJsonData` erases the previous exports...